# Check for overscroll in PageView - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am using PageView in my flutter app. I want to detect when the user overscrolls and is out of pages. How do i achieve it

The code of my PageView:

```
PageView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: widget.imagePaths,
    ),
```

Comment: I don't get the "overscroll" thing. Do you want to check whether if user is currently in either of the first page, or the last page?

Comment: i want to know when the user scrolls beyond the last page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your `PageView` inside a `NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>` like this. Then whenever the user overscrolls in either direction, the function `onNotification` is called.

```
return NotificationListener<
                          OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
                        onNotification: (overscroll) {
                          print("overscrolled"); //do whatever you need to do when overscroll
                        },
                        child: PageView(
                          controller: _controller,
                          children: widget.imagePaths,
                        ),
                      );
```

Full script file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
      onNotification: (overscroll) {
        print("overscrolled");
      },
      child: PageView(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Help!! it is not printing anything. Did it work for you?

Comment: hmm.. it did. Are you correctly placing the `NotificationListener` in the widget tree? and also, is the `PageView` working as intended?

Comment: Yes the `PageView` is working as intended. Do I need to import anything? Can you share your code?

Comment: @Joshua your code (the one you just posted in comments) also works for me. Are there any errors showing? The only thing I imported was `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

Comment: No there are no errors.. Do I need to return anything?

Comment: Please check the full script file I added to the answer.

Comment: Is it printing overscrolled for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231121/discussion-between-joshua-and-rukshanjs).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75254033/9791894

Comment: I could not get the overscroll notification to fire on iOS, maybe because: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17649

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use `NotificationListener<OverscrollNotification>` because then you can choose to which amount of over-scroll you want to react. This is useful if you want to ignore incidental small drag movements.

For example:

```
NotificationListener<OverscrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (OverscrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification.overscroll < 8) {
      // ignore, don't do anything
      return false;
    }

    // do something, for example: load next screen, etc ...

    return true;
  },
  child: PageView(
    controller: _controller,
    children: widget.imagePaths,
  ),
),
```

`8` from above example is result of experiment. You should select the amount which works best for you.

For full example, checkout [this blog post](https://drib.tech/programming/flutter-cookbook-1-swipe-past-last-widget-pageview).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
      onNotification: (overscroll) {
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
         if (notification is OverscrollNotification || 
             notification.metrics.outOfRange) {
              print("Bounced!");
           }
        return false;
      },
      child: PageView(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```